# Trying to install scroll tracking for GA - no events logged in GA Dashboard

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, scroll

I've just built a landing page (speakeasysessions.com) with a number of sections on it and I'd like to track via Google Analytics how far down people scroll before they convert/exit the page.

I found this jquery plugin: http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/ which I've tried to install into my code.

They tell me to do the following:

```
<script src="jquery.scrolldepth.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery.scrollDepth();
});
</script>
```

The plugin can be customized to include sections of the site by id etc. So can be customized. Here's what I've ended up using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
  jQuery.scrollDepth({
    minHeight: 0,
    elements: ['#testimonials','#promise','#cheap-prices','#about'],
    percentage: true,
    userTiming: true,
    pixelDepth: false,
    nonInteraction: false,
  });
  })
```

Which seems simple enough. But no events are being registered on the analytics dashboard, so it's not working at all. Can someone shed light on this? As I'd really like to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the scrolldepth.min.js file is missing from your /js/ directory.

http://speakeasysessions.com/js/jquery.scrolldepth.min.js returns a 404.